# Stripe subscriptions checkout.session.completed resource missing error of invalid_request_error type

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to understand why webhook for `checkout.session.completed` is crashing when testing it locally with the Stripe CLI. I am using djstripe. My webhook for `customer.subscription.created` is successful. With the CLI, I am getting the following error with the `stripe trigger checkout.session.completed` command:

```
Request failed, status=404, body={
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such payment_page: 'ppage_1Il33eAyVjQjzOsRERzYQSbK'",
    "param": "payment_page",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
```

Is the problem with the success url routing?
`views.py`

```
def create_checkout_session(request):
    """Create a checkout session for Stripe."""
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    priceId = data.get("priceId")
    if not Price.objects.filter(id=priceId).exists():
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                             "That plan price is not available. Please contact support for help.", )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("users:index"))
    request.account = OrgMembership.objects.filter(my_identity=request.user).first()
    sessionId = stripegateway.create_checkout_session(priceId, request)
    return JsonResponse({"sessionId": sessionId})
```

`stripegateway.py`

```
class StripeGateway:
    """Gateway interacts with the APIs required by Stripe. Credit: Matt Layman"""
    def create_checkout_session(self, priceId, request):
        """Create a checkout session based on the subscription price."""
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
        subscription_success = reverse("users:success")
        stripe_cancel = reverse("users:stripe_cancel")
        request.account = OrgMembership.objects.get(my_identity=request.user.id)
        request.org = request.account.my_org
        # session_parameters = {
        #     "customer_email": request.org.billing_email,
        #     "success_url": f"http://{site}{subscription_success}",
        #     "cancel_url": f"https://{site}{stripe_cancel}",
        #     "payment_method_types": ["card"],
        #     "mode": "subscription",
        #     "line_items": [{"price": priceId, "quantity": 1}],
        #     "client_reference_id": str(request.account.id),
        # }
        # checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(**session_parameters)
        # return checkout_session["id"]
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            customer_email = request.org.billing_email,
            client_reference_id = str(request.account.id),
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[{
                'price': priceId,
                'quantity': 1,
            }],
            mode='subscription',
            success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('users:success')) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('users:index')),
        )
        return checkout_session["id"]
```

The commented out section is original code used and then tried alternative in efforts to try to fix the problem. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: What line exactly is causing that error? "No such..." errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account). In your case I don't see an obvious place where you are trying to retrieve the payment page.

Comment: @PaulAsjes Thanks. I'm not sure what line is causing the error. The error happens with `stripe trigger checkout.session.completed` command in the stripe CLI. The response does not indicate which line is causing the error, to my knowledge. The success url is where the user is supposed to return to upon checkout completion. Since I am in testing mode I am using the CLI which is supposed to allow for testing using local env. I do not know if this is the issue (that the success url is pointed to local env) or there is an error in my parameters included. Testing subscriptions are successful though

Comment: I am going to mark this as resolved. I think it is a problem with the CLI because webhook now works fine otherwise.

Comment: This can also be caused by not forwarding Stripe webhook events to a development server – see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799816/470560).

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. `stripe trigger checkout.session.completed` would return the following:

```
Trigger failed: Request failed, status=404, body={
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such payment_page: 'ppage_1IryQdFE8p8XoGx4OJLXOv4p'",
    "param": "payment_page",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I fixed the error by updating my stripe CLI version from v1.5.4 to v1.5.14.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to forward the webhook events to a correct and working endpoint.

Use the `forward-to` command line parameter to point the stripe-cli to your development server:

```
stripe listen \
--skip-verify \
--forward-to https://localhost:8000/payments/webhook/ \
--log-level debug
```

The `skip-verify` is needed for self-signed or otherwise invalid certificates when using HTTPS endpoint. Django is also picky about having a slash at the end of URLs.

Comment: I got the exact same error by using just `stripe listen`.